# Remove &sa=U Substring from the URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My website's error log is flooded with 404s for pages containing the `&sa=U` parameter.

Our website does not use this parameter, but Google does, and it is sending users with the URLs containing `&sa=U*` and then the user gets a 404 error page redirection.

I tried using this code, but it's not working.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)?&(.*)$ /$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

For Example:

`https://www.theidioms.com/flash-in-the-pan/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjdmOC119r9AhUM-yoKHT5KAOkQFnoECAEQAg&usg=AOvVaw3vBr3HWgyQ6ny3dHECBgCL`

should be redirected to

`https://www.theidioms.com/flash-in-the-pan/`

Comment: Google does not make up such URLs. Somewhere there is a reference using that URL. That is the cause, that should be fixed. It might be that it is some other page publishing such references, in that case you should find out where that is and contact the responsible person. You can usuall evaluate the referred header in the requests to find out.

Comment: I see, but I think fixing it on our own is a better option.

Comment: A redirection rule is not a _fix_ though, it treats a symptom, but does not fix the cause.

Comment: @CBroe That URL does not actually contain a query string ...

Comment: @arkascha The URL does not contain a query string, which is why it's a rare case.

Comment: @arkascha oops, right, I overlooked that.

Comment: The problem is that due to the greediness of regular expressions, the first capture group matches `flash-in-the-pan/&sa=U`. Include the slash in there, `^(.*/)&(.*)$`, then it should work.

Comment: @CBroe I tried your suggestion, but no luck.

Comment: So what exactly does "not working" mean then? Nothing happening at all, or does a redirect happen, but it goes to a different URL than the desired one?

Comment: @CBroe It's throwing a 404 error, and we previously set 404 to the following URL: https://www.theidioms.com/list/.

Comment: _"It's throwing a 404 error"_ - for the originally requested URL, so no redirect at all happening then? Then you should check if you are even allowed to use mod_rewrite on this server, and whether it even considers .htaccess files for configuration changes in the first place.

Comment: Yes, we are allowed to use mode_rewrite, and we are using WordPress.

Comment: That URL would already seem to be redirected - have you resolve the issue? However, your site does not return a 404 for unknown URLs, you are 301 redirecting to your "list" page (which returns a 200 response) - this is also a "problem" for SEO (and for users to some extent). However, as mentioned earlier, Google does not make up URLs to crawl - it must have found these "parameterized" URLs somewhere (either a misconfiguration, plugin or hack), which would still need to be addressed.

Comment: There is also the matter that Google will not index (or at least return results in organic search) that return a 404 response. So, if Google is returning these results in organic search then those URLs did not return a 404 response when Google crawled. (As mentioned above, unknown URLs are not currently returning a 404 on your site.)

Comment: "error log is flooded with 404s" - The "error log" should not contain 404s in the first place (this is arguably a configuration error). They should be in the "access log" only. By logging 404s in the error log you are polluting the error log and making "real errors" harder to address.

Comment: @MrWhite Actually, it's a dedicated WP plugin for 404 errors, not server error logs.